# Some pages in my android Native app are not inspectable with Appium Desktop

Tags: android, appium, appium-android

Certain pages in our android native app are not inspectable with Appium Desktop and Appium Studio. However with uiAutomatorViewer, I can inspect those screens and take resource-ids. But Appium is unable to locate element with these Ids/xpaths. Did check with dev team but they are not sure about what is going on. Does anyone had similar issues?

Any help or suggestions would appreciated much!!

Comment: Try to be more specific if you can which pages are you having difficulty with, and how are they different from the other pages. This might give someone a better understanding of the context.

Comment: There can be two reasons for the problem , either your app is having web view context or refresh rate of these elements is high.

Answer (score 0):

Before finding element may be you can try getDriver().getPageSource() and by using this it will get the focus of the driver and then try finding elements. If this doesnt help try printing getdriver().getpagesource() in console and try to look whether the element is present in the pagesource or not. if it is there then you can use document builder and parse the pagesource text and get xpath element out of it and once you get the element (this will be generic XML element) get attributes like location and using that tap at that coordinates and this will defenitely work

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem just when dialogs where shown, To have it working I send the app to background for 0 secs, after a dialog was dismissed, and I was able to resume my tests

***Python code***

```
driver.background_app(secs) #you can specify 0 secs
```

***Java code***

```
driver.runAppInBackground(secs) //you can specify 0 secs
```

Let me know if it worked